# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

home.blade.php file
'''

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Dashboard') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    {{ __('You are logged in!') }}
                </div>

                <div class="card-body">
                @csrf

                <form action="/upload" method="post"> 
                <input type="file" name="image">
                <input type="submit" name="upload">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
'''
```

My routes
'''

```
Route::post('/upload',function (){
   return('Halu');
});
```

I don't know where the error is help out as I am a beginner on laravel 8. The route is defined with the function and I don't know where the get or post goes wrong

Comment: Make sure there's no sort of redirect going on, such as from HTTP -> HTTPS. You can watch it in the Network tab of your developer console.

Comment: You get this error on access this page or after click the submit button?

Comment: @sta After clicking submit

Comment: The `@csrf` field is outside the `<form>`, that would explain why you get "page expired" when trying to submit. Did you move it inside the tags as the other answers suggested?

Comment: Yes I did @ppajer but it shows the same 419 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the url in action attribute. and pass `@csrf` token inside the form.

```
<form action="{{ url('/upload')}}" method="post">
 @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Nope didnt solved the error. its still coming. I try to submit it says page expire and then I refresh it . it says the get method is not supported.... error

Comment: It solved the issue. I had to clear the cache after changing the action attribute

Comment: Yeah Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

you try to upload a file you have to set `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your form
it should look like this

```
<form action="{{ url('/upload')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 @csrf
</form>
```

this may solve your issue

Comment: No , I am just trying to pass a dd or return statement just to display the text to show. it shows firstly the page is expire error 419 and when I try to refresh the expired page it shows the get method error